# AddThis API on an iOS Modal View

Tags: ios, crash, modalviewcontroller, addthis

I just started using the AddThis SDK for iOS in order to share URLs and images from my app.
I have a MainViewController, that calls a Modal View Controller named "SummaryViewController".
This segue is performed after a certain button is pressed on the Main View Controller.

There is a UIButton on "SummaryViewController" that is in charge of sharing on Facebook (or any other, for that matter), and performs:

```
-(IBAction)shareOnFacebook { 
   [AddThisSDK shareImage...];
}
```

The thing is that it works !

So where is the problem? When the user goes back to the Main View Controller, by pressing a "Back" button, opens the SummaryViewController **for the second time** and presses the "Share" button, the application crashes, with "unrecognized selector sent to instance", and sometime without any message, and the thread is stuck on [ATCoreController topViewController]

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it? What is different between the first time the VC is shown and the second time?

Thanks a lot !!

in MainViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)showSummary:(id)sender {
    self.summaryViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Summary ViewController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.summaryViewController animated:YES];  
}
```

in SummaryViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)dismissModalViewController:(id)sender {
    [super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What is in your `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a static method in addthis.h.

```
+ (void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;
```

You should set `rootviewcontroller` first time in default it sets your viewcontroller instance, but when you press back and again open `summaryviewcontroller` it searches for `rootviewcontroller` or top `viewcontroller` which was assigned previous one so if that's not available, your application crashes with bad excess.

So use this method to solve your problem before presenting pop-over.